# Get linebreaks/indents with react.renderToStaticMarkup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using react on the server side, but currently html has no line breaks or indents.  that's fine for production, but in development I'd like line breaks and indents.

Is there a way to tell react to use indents when rendering in either `React.renderToString` or `React.renderToStaticMarkup`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass it through a html beautifier.

There aren't any line breaks or indentation because that's the most straightforward implementation.

Comment: Any suggesions of html beautifiers on npm that can add linebreaks where none exist?